# Find out if different home- and lockscreen wallpapers are set

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

I have a running live wallpaper and react to `SCREEN_ON` event to display changes on the canvas. However on some phones the user can set a different lockscreen and homescreen wallpaper (Touchwiz, some Xperia devices). When the user has set a different wallpaper on the lockscreen my live wallpaper is not shown.

On the Galaxy S3 I used `WallpaperService.Engine.isVisible()` and it correctly returns `false` when the user has set a different lockscreen wallpaper. On the Galaxy S3 Mini, however, this does not work, because `isVisible()` returns `true` whether or not my live wallpaper is the active lockscreen wallpaper.

`WallpaperManager.getWallpaperInfo()` or `WallpaperManager.peekDrawable()` don't work either, because `getWallpaperInfo()` returns my live wallpaper regardless of the current lockscreen wallpaper, and `peekDrawable()` returns a valid drawable even if my live wallpaper is set for both screens. I tried listening to `WallpaperService.Engine.onTouchEvent(..)`, but the touch events from the lockscreen don't get through to my live wallpaper, because they are consumed by the unlock slider.

Is there any other way to detect if my live wallpaper is the current lockscreen wallpaper? I'm fine with reflection-hacks, workarounds, everything that will let me do this.

EDIT: it also works on the Galaxy Note 2, bot not on the Xperia T LT30p

Comment: Have you tried WallpaperService.Engine.onVisibilityChanged(..)?

Comment: Yes, `isVisible()` just returns the last value passed to `onVisibilityChanged()`, so they both work on the same data base

Comment: Did you end up solving this? If so, some code would be much appreciated

Comment: @CigogneEveillee Unfortunately not. I talked with the Samsung support, and the behaviour of the S3 Mini is a bug in the firmware, but I don't think they have a high priority to fix it. That's how far I got.

Answer (score 2):

Lockscreen wallpaper is not supported by AOSP version of Android. The feature is entirely made by OEMs (Samsung, Sony, LG, etc.) and thus APIs for dealing with the lockscreen wallpaper are totally different among OEMs. Furthermore, some OEMs only do not support live wallpapers on loockscreens while others do.

Since they are OEM added APIS, you should use reflections to access them. However, it will work on one OEM devices, but the same code will not work on other OEMs' devices.

Comment: Thanks, I know all that and I'm fine with device-specific hacks for the moment.

Comment: Actually, starting from API 24, it is possible. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51310448/878126

Answer (score 0):

Starting from API 24, you can use [**WallpaperManager.getWallpaperFile**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager#getWallpaperFile(int)) :

[image]

Then you can get which wallpaper is of which type.

Another alternative is [**WallpaperManager.getWallpaperId**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager#getWallpaperId(int)) :

[image]